# Why do code chunks always have a syntax error?

Tags: syntax, knitr, chunks

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
options (stringsAsFactors = F)
```
````

I get a red line (syntax error) from the first line for all my code chunks. Can someone explain to me how to fix this and also what exactly the purpose of code chunks are? Do I need them or can I just write a script without them?

Comment: The code snipped you presented does not contain any syntax error. What is your goal? If you just want an R script, you don't need to use knitr. However, if you want an document with embedded R snippets, then you *do* need code chunks. What is your actual goal? Can you provide a [mcve]? Why do you think you need the code above?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using code chunks in an R script.  Code chunks are a way to embed R scripts in other documents; the example you have would be for an R Markdown document.  You can't use the first or last line in an actual R script; they are signals to R Markdown saying that what is between them is R code.

For example, many R blogs and help pages embed examples using that syntax.  See https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ for general instructions and a tutorial containing lots of examples.